# Concisely operate on RHS of list of rules

Tags: map, rule

I have a length-N list of rules

```
l = {a -> 5, b -> 1, c -> 42}
```

and an length-N vector of scalars...

```
dl = {-1, .2, 5}
```

which I'd like to *add* to the RHS of rules, to produce

```
{a -> 5 -1, b -> 1 +.2, c -> 42 +5}
```

I can currently achieve this verbosely with

```
Table[l[[t, 1]] -> l[[t, 2]] + dl[[t]], {t, Length[l]}]
```

but I'm looking for the most concise method possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) with [`AddTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AddTo):

```
l = {a -> 5, b -> 1, c -> 42};
dl = {-1, .2, 5};

l[[All, 2]] += dl;
l
```

> {a -> 4, b -> 1.2, c -> 47}

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much!